# Transfer values between pages in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am working on Oracle APEX 5 and wanted to transfer values added into List manager (in page 2) to display them on Page 3 as read-only. How can we do that?

What type of item to choose to display values in page 3? and how to get these values from list manager?
please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The List Manager item type can hold multiple values, which are delimited by a colon e.g. '7782:7902:7788:7698'.  If you pass this item value to a hidden item in the target page then you can call `apex_string.split` to convert it to an array of values, which you can then process as you wish.  For example, if the values are EMPNOs and you want to display all the names in a display only item you can write code like:

```
declare
  empno_array wwv_flow_t_varchar2;
begin
  empno_array := apex_string.split (:P3_HIDDEN_ITEM, ':');
  select listagg (ename, ', ') within group (order by ename)
    into :P3_DISPLAY_ITEM
    from emp
   where empno in (select column_value
                     from table(empno_array));
end;
```